# writeable common table expression and multiple insert statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

How do I write the following in a valid Postgres SQL query:

```
with foo as (select * from ...)
insert into bar select * from foo
insert into baz select * from foo
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use CTEs, if you want this all in one statement:

```
with foo as (
      select * from ...
     ),
     b as (
      insert into bar
          select * from foo
          returning *
     )
insert into baz
    select * from foo;
```

Notes:

- You should include column lists with `insert`.
- You should specify the column names *explicitly* for the `select *`.  This is important because the columns may not match in the two tables.
- I always use `returning` with `update`/`insert`/`delete` in CTEs.  This is the normal use case -- so you can get serial ids back from an insert, for instance.

Comment: this is giving me the following error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 73: b as (
              ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1778
@Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Sam . . . There is no line 73 in this answer.  If you have a question, then ask a *new* question.

Comment: yes sorry I was trying to implement this logic in my code, turns out I was using an alias for ' foo' which gave me an error on 'b as (' but when I removed the alias, it worked!
@Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

A `with` clause's scope is just a single query. The only solution I can think of is to create a view and drop it when you're done inserting. It won't be completely ephemeral like a CTE, but there's no data duplication here - just a (relatively) cheap DDL operation:

```
-- Create the view
CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT * FROM ...;

-- Perform the inserts
INSERT INTO bar SELECT * FROM foo;
INSERT INTO baz SELECT * FROM foo;

-- Drop the view when you're done
DROP VIEW foo;
```

Comment: You _can_ do that with a single CTE, no need for a (temporary) view.