# SQL Server CTE with multiple insert statements

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Can I use multiple CTE INSERT expressions with SQL Sever?

This is allowed in PostgreSQL:

[writeable common table expression and multiple insert statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107447/writeable-common-table-expression-and-multiple-insert-statements)

e.g in PostgreSQL.

```
with foo as 
(
      select * from ...
),
b as 
(
      insert into bar
          select * from foo
          returning *
)
insert into baz
    select * from foo;
```

I have tried in SQL Server:

```
;WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM Foo       
),
cte2 AS ( -- depends on cte1
    SELECT * FROM Bar WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM cte1)
),
cte3 AS ( -- first insert
    INSERT INTO Baz1
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*
    SELECT * FROM cte2
)
INSERT INTO Baz2 -- second insert depends on ct3 data-set
SELECT * FROM cte3
```

The above does not work.

Comment: No, SQL Server does not support that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, What are my options then? should I write to a temp table the first insert? and then move that to the real 2 tables?

Comment: You can join foo to bar in the cte.

Comment: @JoeC, Yes I know but that is not my problem. The above is only a simplified example.

Comment: You may need to write the first insert into temp table  and perform the rest of the logic..Multiple insertsql se within nested CTE is not allowed.

Comment: If you provide a better example someone might be able to pose a solution.  Maybe doing a unionized subquery or some such approach.

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, I'd look into using a `trigger` in MS SQL Server (plus the `inserted` temp table that it'll have access to) - Further info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15). Another useful link [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-create-trigger/).

How I'd approach your problem is to think of it as two separate chunks of code:

- **First chunk** (Run first insert statement from two CTEs):

> ```
> ;WITH cte1 AS 
> (
>     SELECT * FROM Foo       
> ),
> cte2 AS ( -- depends on cte1
>     SELECT * FROM Bar WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM cte1)
> )
> INSERT INTO Baz1
> SELECT * 
> FROM cte2
> ```

- **Second chunk** (Trigger that exists in the Baz1 table that runs after an INSERT into the table):

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER [Some_unique_trigger_name] ON Baz1
> AFTER INSERT
> AS
> BEGIN
>     SET NOCOUNT ON;
>     INSERT INTO Baz2(
>         column_names
>     )
>     SELECT *
>     FROM inserted i
> END
> ```

You'll have to first update the queries to match the column names / table names / trigger names etc.